# React Issue with websocket connection

Tags: reactjs, webpack, websocket, connection

I have problem with websockets after make npm run build in docker conteiner, like: WebSocket connection to 'wss://sibautocom.net:3000/ws' failed, i don't use permanent conversation of my client side with server and want to disable or solve this issue, I will glad every help.

I'll try to permanently disable webpack-dev-server to disable webpack, but in my case docker make npm install after docker-compose up build and thts why I can't make changes in node modules, I need to change programmaticly or may be exist some flags to npm run builds to prevent websockets, but I don't find them

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the answer, this happens because the `docker compose` initiates `npm run build`, but after I don't use the compression and optimized files, after docker init npm start, that means I'm starting `dev-server` inside docker.

My dear DevOps just correct `docker compose` file and ecosystem config like that: you add this part RUN `npm install -g` serve to your `docker compose` file, and after npm build for your frontend part you need to run `serve -s build -p 3000`.